# MonoTouch: can't generate WCF proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, virtual-machine

I run Win7x64 under MacOs (Lion) via VMware Fusion. On this Win7 i run simple WCF service, wich i succesful consume from client on win7. 
Now i need consume this service from my MonoTouch solution, but i can't generate WCF proxy. When i try to generate proxy via MonoDevelope i get next error:
[image]
But i can succesul get WSDL from web browser:
[image]
What was my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this recently - instead of using the MonoDevelop tools, use SlSvcUtil from the Silverlight 3, 4 or 5 SDK under Windows - then just transfer the file(s) across to the Mac

This tutorial is pretty much exactly what I did: http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF

Comment: link is broken, I'd imagine this one is similar [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Windows_Communication_Foundation_WCF](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Windows_Communication_Foundation_WCF)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the high port number is disallowed. Try a lower port such as 81.

I have had problems like this before which have been solved by using a lower port.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's doesn't help.